# Applying several filters using Redux Selectors and Reselect, what is better?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect, redux-selector

I have three filtering functions In my `selectors.js` file, which take `state` and return filtered `state`,
let's say :

```
filter1(state){...}; 
filter2(state){...}; 
filter3(state){...};
```

I need to combine them together so that the `state` could go through all of them if several filters are applied simultaneously.
**So I have several questions:**

1. How do I do it using Redux Reselect library?
2. Is it a good idea to just make 4th function and call all three functions in a recursive way like this in terms of readability and best pactice?

```
   combineFilters(state) {
        return filter3(filter2(filter1(state)));
    }
```

3. Can I just make a `Class` and define all three filters as a `Class` methods to chain them like this? (Is it a good idea to use `Classes` outside main react `Component` logic?)

```
   const resultData = Data.filter1().filter2().filter3()
```